# GridView sorting: SortDirection

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with ASP gridview sorting. I have a mistake, but I can't find it...grid always sort one direction.

```
    string _ordering_fieldname
            {
                get { return ViewState["column"] == null ? "adr" : (string)ViewState["column"]; }
                set { ViewState["column"] = value; }
            }

            string _ordering_direction
            {
                get { return ViewState["direction"] == null ? "asc" : (string)ViewState["direction"]; }
                set { ViewState["direction"] = value; }
            }

protected void Spisok_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            _OrderingField ordering = new _OrderingField(e.SortExpression);
            switch (e.SortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending: ordering.orderingDirection = OrderingDirection.Ascending; _ordering_direction = "asc"; break;
                case SortDirection.Descending: ordering.orderingDirection = OrderingDirection.Descending; _ordering_direction = "desc"; break;
                default: ordering.orderingDirection = OrderingDirection.Ascending; _ordering_direction = "asc"; break;
            }
            _ordering_fieldname = ordering.fieldName;

            //here I call refreshing my grid with sorting
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you need to use your _ordering_fieldname & _ordering_direction values

```
//here I call refreshing my grid with sorting
var dt = GetFromDatabaseFunction();
var dv = dt.DefaultView();
dv.Sort = _ordering_fieldname + " " + _ordering_direction;

GridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to set the properties when you update the grid sort direction.

Comment: he is setting it above in his codes :) codes i've provided is just the continuation of his codes.

Comment: Ah, OK fair point, I actually didn't notice the end of the case statement.